# Can I still use OEM steering wheel controls with an aftermarket head unit?

Tags: ford, audio, steering-wheel, mustang

I own a 2014 Ford Mustang with Sync.  Sync is pretty mediocre and can sometimes be frustrating.  I'm interested in switching to an aftermarket head unit, not unlike this one:

[Parrot RNB6](http://blog.parrot.com/2015/01/05/ces-2015-parrot-rnb6-the-most-advanced-in-vehicle-infotainment-system/)

I'd like to know if switching to this will render my steering wheel controls inoperable.  Particularly the Voice Command button, volume, etc.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but at a glance, I would say you are out of luck ... don't trust my answer here. Hopefully someone is more authoritative on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's technically possible. but in general it requires you or an electrician to make up custom wiring harnesses. In other words: you can't just install the head unit and expect it to work. That would be too simple. Real men have to suffer before they're allowed to enjoy something.

The good news is that Parrot thought of this and offers the [UNIKA](http://www.parrot.com/usa/products/steering-wheel-controls/) interface.

Comment: That's an impressive solution.  Hopefully I can get it to work.

Comment: While you're at it, get yourself an OBD2 bluetooth dongle and download the Torque app onto the device.

Comment: The RNB already provides diagnostic capability through the obd II port.

Answer (score 2):

I do a fair bit of ICE (although mostly European and Japanese cars) and from my experience, unless one of the aftermarket providers has built an adapter you are usually out of luck. There are just too many different standards (or lack of them) for how steering wheel controls talk to head units.

That said - replacements are often very cheap, or you can often replace the actual switches while keeping the fascia controls in place.

Comment: Where can I find out more about replacing the switches?  I really don't want to have unused buttons or have to tack some add-on onto the steering column.

Comment: In looking into the specifics for your setup, I don't think you'll have any luck doing it this way unless you are experienced with disassembling and modifying electronics.